# “I have come to” vs. “I have came to”

Tags: verbs, present-perfect, irregular-verbs

I am not a native English speaker, and I learn from people.

I often hear people say “**I have come to a place** where there is no end…”.
I am wondering, isn't the right way to say it: “I have **came**” (I know that sounds awful, I am asking what's proper)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The past participle of the verb *to come* is **come**, so you should say “I have come to a place where…”. *came* is the past tense (or preterite), so you would say “I came to a place where…”.

Answer (score 8):

"I have come to a place where[…]" is correct, as *I have come* is the Present Perfect tense.
*Came* is used in sentences like "I came to visit you", where the used tense is the Simple Past.

When to use the Present Perfect, and when to use the Simple Past, is then [a different topic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/present-perfect-tense-versus-past-tense).

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide a link to that different topic? Also, what about "GO" "I has gone to the shadows" etc.

Comment: With _go_, the present perfect is _I have gone_, and the simple past is _I went_.