# Is "I just spent all my money" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammaticality, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Lyircs of *Free* by Natalia Kills:

> I'm free
>
> I just spent all my money
>
> but I rocked that like it don't cost a thing

Shouldn't it be "I've just spent all my money"? As far as I remember, our English told us to use Present Prefect in such case because of the just.

Comment: I don't think there's anything grammatically *wrong* with the usage. In some contexts there might be ambiguity about whether *just* means *very recently* or *merely*, but it seems to me that applies whether you use the present perfect *(I have just spent)* or the simple past *(I just spent)*.

Comment: Off topic (lit crit/lyrics interpretation request).

Comment: @MετάEd It's NOT a lyrics interpretation request, just because the question quotes lyrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

American English tends to use the past tense in places where British English uses the present perfect construction, and this may be one such place. But in any case, the lyrics of popular music are not always written in Standard English and will consequently conform to a different set of grammatical rules.

Comment: Indeed, "like it don't cost a thing" wouldn't win any points from a composition teacher either, but it's a song, not an essay.

Answer (score 2):

Either one works. Anything that happened in the past can usually be expressed in the past tense.

If it's important in some way that the past event(s) are over and done with, or for [some other reasons](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53180/must-present-perfect-tense-be-used-if-the-action-takes-place-more-than-once/53188#53188), the Perfect construction can also be used. But it's rarely necessary, except for emphasis and in idioms and fixed phrases like *have got, [have gotten](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/gotten.html),* and *have been to*.