# The correct usage of past tense with just

Tags: past-tense

I understand that phrase:

> "I have just bought a house".

is correct.

But I also saw, that sometimes people could say:

> "I just bought a house."

Is it correct?

Comment: The presence or absence of the word ***just*** has no bearing on whether or not you include ***have***. This question is purely about simple past vs past perfect. The word just is irrelevant.

Comment: From Google Ngrams, this advice (I assume from ESL classes) appears to be [100 years out of date](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+have+just+seen%3Aeng_us_2012%2CI+just+saw%3Aeng_us_2012%2CI+have+just+seen%3Aeng_gb_2012%2CI+just+saw%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=8&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20have%20just%20seen%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20just%20saw%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20have%20just%20seen%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20just%20saw%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), both for the U.S. and the U.K.

Comment: We see this question a lot, as it appears this rule is taught in ESL classes. Looking at 19th century Google books hits for *"I just saw"*, the majority of them seem to mean *"I only saw"*. So back then, my guess is that if you used *"just"* (and you weren't speaking some non-standard dialect), you automatically switched the verb to present perfect. This is not the case today. So this advice does seem to be based in fact, just obsolete fact.

Comment: As Peter implies, there is an extra dimension if we consider whether ***just*** has the sense of ***merely, simply, only***, or the (more recent, I think) sense of ***very recently***. As in *"I just bought the house, I didn't buy the farm"*.

Comment: I just saw the future, but I prefer the past. Actually, I'd use the past simple after 'just' only in informal registers.

Comment: I see no `Close` votes yet, so perhaps I have time for an answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am sympathetic to that view too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The use of temporal *just* with a Perfect construction evokes [the ***Hot News!*** sense of the Perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/15299).

This sense is almost always used for recent events of great importance. Generally the Past is OK, too.

- *Botswana has just invaded Uruguay.*
- *Botswana invaded Uruguay this morning.*

In the case of the original examples, the event is certainly important enough

- *I've just bought a house.*
- *I just bought a house.*

but there is no real difference in meaning or use, no grammatical or semantic distinction, between the two. Although certain sentences sound odd with one or the other form, because of irrelevant restrictions on individual constructions.

Different speakers with different habits and experience will probably see potential distinctions to make, but nobody will see or make the same ones. When either choice is OK, a speaker chooses the one that sounds best to them, for whatever reasons they may have.

Answer (score 5):

In my idiolect, as for many speakers of British English, the simple past is incompatible with temporal *just*: I would say *I have just sold a house* but not *I just sold a house*.

For many (?most) speakers of American English, and increasingly in Britain as well, *I just sold a house* is grammatical.

As others have said, there is another meaning of *just* ("only", "merely") which is compatible with either tense.

[I changed "bought" to "sold" because I have, in fact, just sold a house].

Comment: Indeed one could safely say 'for (all) speakers of American English, *I just sold a house* is grammatical'.