# Newspaper headlines + is it possible to use present perfect?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, perfect-aspect

I've found these two sentences in newspaper headlines and there are two things I am not sure about:

> 1. Haas beats  Wawrinka
>      Tommy Haas **claimed** the biggest win of the season against Wawrinka. He beats #3 in the World 5-7/ 6-2/ 6-3 and reach the quarterfinal in Rome. On the Foto is Tommy with a icepack after the match. Now he has 1.45 hours rest before the doubles start.
>      [Source](http://www.tennis-university.com/tommy-beats-wawrinka/)

Do I understand it right that there could be **has claimed** but because of newspaper style—it is perfect to use shorter past simple? Is it the same like: *Three people **killed** in a car accident?* Present perfect would be possible as well but it would be too long for this purpose.

> 2. Federer *forgets* **he's won** the match. 
>      [source](https://twitter.com/perfecttennisuk/status/477836319633444864)

This surprised me a lot. I thought it wasn't possible to use the present perfect in headlines.

- Why do you think the writer decided to use that tense? Was it for emphasis?

For me it is an unusual combination  to use the present simple (forgets) and then the present perfect in newspaper headlines. The first is used to keep headlines short; however, in this case it doesn't make sense as it is followed by the longer present perfect construction.

The last thing is that I am not sure whether it is possible to switch tenses whenever I want. I´ll give you an example:

> **Headline**:
>
> Federer *beats* Djokovic in the 2nd round
>
> **The article**
>
> Federer has been beaten by Djokovic for the third consecutive time and will not defend his Wimbledon crown. Djokovic *beats* him easily and didn't allow him any break.

The thing I am not sure about is whether journalists can switch from one tense to another, see the following example:  "Djokovic beats.."  or whether it is acceptable to do so only  in the headlines?

Comment: related: [Why is the present perfect used in headlines?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69323/why-is-the-present-perfect-used-in-headlines)

Comment: Newspapers take considerable licence in the way they compose headlines. One requirement is to economise on words - so often they do not make grammatical sense.The simple present for something that has just happened is perfectly idiomatic anyway, in the context of a news report, especially a headline.

Comment: After looking for the sources, none of them seem to me particularly reputable. The first has a number of other problems which puzzle me much more e.g. "on the Foto..." And I wouldn't call either of them newspaper articles, these are "news" written on the fly, with little pre-thought or reflection. The second "headline" is a tweet.

Comment: also related: [Why do newspaper headlines use strange syntax rules?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7257/why-do-newspaper-headlines-use-strange-syntax-rules) and [Does the present perfect imply an action finished in the past?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/221312/does-the-present-perfect-imply-an-action-finished-in-the-past)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thanks Mari-Lou A - I don´t get it. Is it possible to use present perfect in the second example? Can I use present perfect when I am writing a headline - in combination with present simple? In the first example - can I take it the way that past simple "claimed" was used because of headline? Or is it situated too far that it can be considered to be a headline?

Comment: The first headline is a bit of a mess, this is not good journalism "reach the quarterfinal" should be *"reaches the quarterfinal"* The next error,  *On the Foto* should be "in the photo" but even that sounds clumsy, I would say "*The photo shows Tommy with an icepack..." The second "headline" doesn't make sense, it should be something like: *"Federer doesn't realize he's won the match"*

Comment: The present perfect works here because as John Lawler says PP expresses "hot" news, it sounds more urgent, more dynamic. In any case, I don't believe the examples are written by real journalists, especially the first which contains so many basic errors.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Thank you very much. I don´t know whether it makes much sense  to analyse sentence which is not written correctly but there is one more thing I am curious about - "Tommy Haas claimed the biggest win of the season against Wawrinka. He beats #3 in the World .... "  Is it really possible and usual to use normal tenses like " claimed" and then continue by using "headline tense" =he beats - which I would expect to see in the headline only. Thanks

Comment: I said: *I don't believe the examples are written by real journalists, especially the first which contains so many basic errors* Basic errors include the mixing up tenses; it should read "He beat the number 3 [seed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seed_%28sports%29) 5-7/ 6-2/ 6-3..." Beat is an irregular verb, it's: *beat*, *beat*, *beaten*. http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/irregular-verbs/beat.html

Comment: @Mari-LouA  It wasn´t the best example I could give you but it was meant to be in general. Let me give you another one: Headline: " Federer beats Djokovic in the 2nd round" The article " Federer has been beaten by Djokovic for the third consecutive time and will not defend his Wimbledon crown. Djokovic beats him easily and didn´t allow him any break." The thing I am not sure about is whether journalists can use "the headline tense" in the article (see the " Djokovic beats.." in my example) or just in the headline? Thanks!

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Ok. I have edited my original post.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Ok, thank you. Do you think it is ok now?  I am still learning how this forum works :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Would it be possible to help me with my last question about the switching of the tenses? Please :)

Comment: Where did the article come from? I need to see it in its entirety. But the headline looks fine to me, typical journalistic style. Personally I wouldn't write: *Djokovic beats him easily and didn't allow him any break.* Both verbs should either be in the simple past or present simple.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I created the sentences by myself. But I think you may have already answered the question. I wasn´t sure whether or not I could use that journalistic style for example in the middle of the article (after I had used "normal" tenses) - or whether it is possible to do so in the headline/ in the first sentences only.