# In the tense of present perfect, Are 'recent past' and 'hot news' the same?

Tags: grammar

In the tense of present perfect, I learned that
"I have finished the work" means 'recent past' and "The man has died"means'hot news'
Are 'recent past' and 'hot news' the same in meaning?

Comment: I think you have oversimplified. *The man has died*, could be "recent past" (The man has *just* died) or "hot news" (John Q has died) it depends on the context, and on the subject. I think you took these examples from answers on EL&U, it would help other users if you cited these questions and answers. Just one or two links would be fine.

Comment: Hot news? What is that??

Comment: @Lambie the "hot news" is taken from this answer http://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/44619, the user who uses this term is **John Lawler**.

Comment: @John Lawler - I see. Well, how is one expected to know these things? Sounds like coded language if you don't know the reference...which is only to some other post here. As they say: you hadda be there.