# What category does the 'the recent perfect' belong to?

Tags: grammar

A scholar has said that there are 4 usages of the present past tense:

- The **Universal** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate that a state of affairs prevailed throughout some interval stretching from the past into the present

  > *I've known Max since 1960.*
- The **Existential** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate the existence of past events

  > *I have read Principial Mathematica five times.*
- The **Stative/Resultative** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate that the direct effect of a past event still continues

  > *I can't come to your party tonight - I've caught the flu.*
- The **Hot News** sense of the Perfect, used to report hot news

  > *Malcolm X has just been assassinated.*

To what category does *the recent past* belong?

Comment: There is no "present past tense".  It seems you're talking about the present perfect.  Please give the link to "scholar". I don't find the classifications very useful, but maybe that's just me.  The present perfect describes states or actions completed in some past interval up to the present time.  Depending on the example, any past tense could refer to the "recent past."

Comment: You need to cite the author, who is [**John Lawler**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69323/why-is-the-present-perfect-used-in-headlines/69335#69335), and say where you found this question and answer. Why are you repeating the same question? This is the third (that I know of) question asking about the same thing.

Comment: Please don't ask similar questions within a short period of time. Possible duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328013/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-hot-news-and-recent-past-in-the-presen

Comment: @Mari-LouA well, 3 gold badges were awarded for *something* (famous question x3).

Comment: @MariLouA The author is McCawley, as cited by John Lawler in your link.

Comment: @Spagirl whatever, I only looked briefly at the linked post, the OP needs to cite who the author is and where he found these definitions. This isn't the first time I asked, the OP instead just posts a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar gives the following definition:

> Present Perfect of the Recent Past: a present perfect used to express the actuality of a recent past event, also called the Hot News Present Perfect.

Comment: @Rathony Thank you. I'm pretty sure there weren't 5 down votes at the time I replied, but I'll keep an eye out for that in future. I replied because the question had made me curious about the 'Hot News' thing so I had looked it up and it seemed churlish not to share what I found. I only asked the OP to 'accept' as he was criticised in other comments for never doing so and it seemed an opportunity to engage while he was actively commenting, (since we can't '@' him) and describing an answer as correct. Be assured it won't be my habit to pester for answers to be accepted.