# Using present perfect in recent past question?

Tags: verbs, present-perfect, filler-words

The recent water crisis in Johannesburg ____ global attention.

A) gained
B) has gained

I think both of the answers are correct. Because it's talking about the recent past then *has gained* can be used. But the water crisis is no more relevant as it is not continuing in the current time. So *gained* can be used. 
Can someone please explain which answer is correct and explain it. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, both are grammatical. The perfect is an example (literally, it appears) of [the _Hot News!_ sense](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/15299) of the perfect construction.