# What's the difference between present perfect and present perfect continuous?

Tags: present-perfect, learning

I need to know if this two sentences have different meaning

a) The client *has been telling* us that the site is likely to be around the Krakow area.
B) The client *has told* us that the site is likely to be around the Krakow area

Comment: In this context, _has been telling_ means there have been at least two instances of the client saying this; _has told_ means there has been at least one such instance. The continuous here indicates repetition.

Comment: @JohnLawler Is it not also possible that the client has only just finished talking to the speaker and that the explanation was quite lengthy? That would be analogous to "The client has only just left, he has been telling us about the benefits to the community of the project going ahead".

Comment: Yes, the [Hot News sense of the Perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/15299) is also possible. In this case, _just_ could be inserted after _has_.

Answer (score 0):

Has been telling (for some period of time, either continuously or episodically)

Has told us (the telling, no matter when or in what manner, has ended)