# simple past or present perfect issue

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, present-perfect, simple-past

I would like to ask the reason of using present perfect tense instead of past tense in the italic words in the sentence below:

> She has gotten older since we last met her. She also seems to *have become* funnier.

Is it because the meaning would contain the message that “she had become funnier for a while after we last met her. But she is not funnier than before anymore.” if we use a past tense here?

Thank you.

Comment: _The perfect tense or aspect is a verb form that indicates that an action or circumstance occurred earlier than the time under consideration, often focusing attention on the resulting state rather than on the occurrence itself_ (Wikipedia). The perfect is used here because the past changes affect how the lady appears _now_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Thank you so much for your help‍♀️☺️

Comment: The first sentence uses a [resultative present perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/15299) construction to comment on one change that has occurred over a period of time,  and it is also used in the second sentence commenting on another change that has occurred during the same time. It's a straightforward parallel construction.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment wrote John Lawler:

> The first sentence uses a [resultative present perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/69335/15299) construction to comment on one change that has occurred over a period of time,  and it is also used in the second sentence commenting on another change that has occurred during the same time. It's a straightforward parallel construction.