# Meaning of "… is king"

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

The word **king** alone is not an adjective. And since it is countable it should be either **a king** or **the king**. So the expressions like "*money is king*" or "*the Lord is king*" are ungrammatical. How would you explain it, and what meaning **king** bears here?

Comment: Curiously EL&U users have been known to say "Context is king" http://english.stackexchange.com/a/111341/44619 and http://english.stackexchange.com/a/140863/44619 Safe to say that the expression is grammatical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*King* is the title of the king, and titles can be used in the same manner as proper nouns; that is, some require articles and some do not.

If money is figuratively the king, then money is king.

The second example would more likely be "Christ is King", as Christ is indeed considered to be a king, and hence to have that title (and the title Lord, but using the two titles like that would be less common).

Comment: Titles shouldn't begin  with a capital letter (King)?

Comment: Macmillan says that 'X is king' (X not a crowned head of state) is a 'phrase' (I'd say idiom): PHRASES

... 
**something is king**
something that influences a lot of people
_a time when jazz was king_ It also points out the special article-less usage of King for Jesus.

Comment: I don't think titles explain why this usage is ok. Consider “his pen is poison.” I suspect that the correct answer has more to do with the use of nouns as modifiers, as in noun adjuncts.

Comment: @BraddSzonye: *poison* is also a mass noun, like *water* or *butter*, and hence doesn't require an article.