# "I bought (or) have bought all their records after the concert"

Tags: past-tense, present-perfect, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

> I have bought all their records after the concert.
>
> I bought all their records after the concert.

Which one is correct?

I understand when we use the present perfect and when the past simple, I just wanted to know if the expression '**after the concert**' could also mean the period of time since the concert and up to the present day?

Would that allow the use of the present perfect?

Comment: If you didn't buy them at the venue, you need "I have bought all their records since [attending] the concert."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth , what extra context does the present perfect add here? it's assumed the records are still in your possession, and hence, I don't see why not to use the past simple here. the first one sounds extremely fancy and redundant.

Comment: @kimuse this is one of these cases where both sentences are grammatically correct, the question is which one is more natural, and in what context these two are supposed to be said.

Comment: But both sentences aren't grammatical. It is ungrammatical to use the present perfect with a designated point in time like "after the concert." Similarly, "I have been to India 2 years ago" is also ungrammatical.

Comment: @David Haim As opposed to 'I have bought all their records after the concert.' The 'since' licenses 'have bought'.

Comment: Is 'after the concert' considered a specific designated point. Can't it be considered after the concert a period up to now?

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you help clarify my doubt? Thank you!

Comment: If you want to say that you bought their records (which is rather outdated) in the days, weeks and months after the concert then you need "since" in No. 1. Edwin Ashworth's modified sample is pretty much perfect. P.S You need to add @ and the username if you want to communicate with a user

Comment: "I bought all his books after May 1st" This doesn't tell us if the speaker is still buying that author's books in February 2018. It could do but it's unlikely. "Since May 1st I have bought every Clancy's book" hints that I have not stopped buying his books. Whenever a new book is published, I will buy it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA : Ok. I don't know how this site works. But can someone tell me if ''why have i lost so much weight after pregnancy?'' is correct, why can't I say  'I have bought all their records after the concert'?

Comment: Hmm... not all the questions listed above are good matches, the best one (in your case) is  [Must present perfect tense be used if the action takes place more than once?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53180/must-present-perfect-tense-be-used-if-the-action-takes-place-more-than-once)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  I think I've always being polite when asking my questions and I don't really think it the case to be so rude! I didn't expect anything I was just looking for help. Obviously this is not the place. I've never said I was upset. You're really making things up. I was just asking politely for clarification. Didn't know this was considered so offensive. I did read the posts related to my questions and did after edited my post. I've never seen such a rude way to reply. I just leave this forum if there are no moderators stopping comments like yours.

Answer (score 1):

The second sentence is grammatically correct.
We use simple past tense in these cases:

1. Showing an action which started in past and ended in past, too
   Example: *I met him yesterday*
2. Referring to one's habit in the past
   Example: *He never drank coffee*
3. An action which happened in a certain period in past.
   Example: *He worked in the company for 2 years*
4. Referring to 2 actions that happened immediately after each other.
   Example: *When the teacher entered, they stood up*.

We use present perfect tense in following cases:

1. The action happened in the past but we see the effect of that action in present.
   For example: *I have lost my keys*

Note: if the action does not have any effect till the present tense we can not use present perfect in this case we should use simple past tense.

2. Referring to an action which happened several times in the past.
   Example: *he has visited London 10 times*.
3. An action which started in past but continues till present and may continue in future, too.
   Example: *He has been in the army for 2 years*.
   *We have worked all day.*
4. We can use this tense to show that an action has happened earlier than expected time (use "already" in this case)
   Example: A) "don't forget to mail the letter"
   B) *I've already mailed them*.

**we can also use "since" with present perfect to talk about a period that started at some point in the past and continues until the present time**

Note: the main difference between simple past and present perfect is that simple past expresses an event or action at a specific time while present perfect expresses an action at an indefinite time.
The first sentence, you wrote has problem according to my explanations

References: *Advanced English Grammar in Use* by Martin Hewings, *English Grammar Digest* by Trudy Aronson.
*practical English grammar*by S.Anari

Comment: Ok, thank you. So the second sentence is wrong? Because if I say I've bought all their records after the concert, it could also mean: after the concert up to now.  Right? So I could also say the second one, or not? Thanks

Comment: @kimuse No, the first sentence is wrong; the second sentence is right. People don't actually use the present perfect the way someone told you they do.

Comment: @kimuse According to my explanations the first sentence is wrong but the second one is correct.just remeber this point:present perfect is not used with a designated time while simple past can be used with a designated time.I mentioned it in my post too....you can see in your first sentence present perfect is used with a special time"after the concert" this is sth that makes your first sentence wrong,but second sentence does not have problem because simple past can be used with a special time .

Comment: Ok, I understand you explanation thank you. I was just asking if ''after the concert'' could also be intended as since the concert up to now.