# Can present perfect tense express an experience since a specific time

Tags: grammar

Present perfect can express a life experience, for example:

> I've seen a volcanic eruption.

Can it express an experience starting from a specific time? For example:

> Since 2015, I've seen a volcanic eruption.

Comment: Makes more sense if followed by a list: Since then, I've seen A, B, and C.

Comment: You need another time expression, or a continuous verb: "Since 2015 I've seen a volcano eruption every few months" or "Since 2015 I've been seeing volcanic eruptions."

Comment: This is so weird. It makes sense, and it should work, but for some reason it doesn't sound idiomatic. I can't even think of a non-awkward way to rephrase. "At some point between 2015 and now, I've seen a volcanic eruption."

Comment: After careful consideration, I think the weirdness lies in what happened before 2015. There's two possibilities. One is I saw a volcanic eruption before 2015. The other is I did not see one before 2015. If the first situation applies, why do I say "Since 2015, I've seen ..." If the second situation applies, why do I mention 2015? Does 2015 have special significance?

Comment: This is the [Existential use of the Perfect](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53188/15299), which occurs with punctual predicates and indicates the existence of one or more events in the past.

Comment: "I don't think there has been a volcanic eruption on Elbonia since 2066 ... has anyone here actually _seen_ a volcanic eruption since 2066?"