# Why is using "have" or "have had" necessary?

Tags: have

Just one example I recently saw, I also hear people talking this way, and wonder why.

Washington Post title today reads, "Many who have received the coronavirus vaccine wonder..."

Another news title reads, "People who have had the vaccine..."

Why is it necessary to add "have" or "have had" instead of simplifying the statement with, "Many who received the coronavirus vaccine wonder..."?

Just seems like adding extra words, which looks/sounds wordy instead of getting to the point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/when-is-the-present-perfect-tense-used-instead-of-the-past-tense)

Comment: *People who have had the vaccine* uses **have** to add emphasis.

Comment: @Greybeard— You are right. I don't know why I misread it. Thanks for pointing it out. I of course had in mind present perfect, not present continuous.