# What is the difference between "Look who has decided to show up" and "Look who decided to show up"?

Tags: present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I always get confused between deciding whether to use present perfect or past simple with expressions like these. So how can I use them correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the present perfect tense used instead of the past tense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1357/when-is-the-present-perfect-tense-used-instead-of-the-past-tense)

Comment: @livresque I'm not sure the answers there apply to this type of use.

Comment: "Look who decided" sounds more idiomatic to me.